# Horizontal scaling: routing user-generated subdomains between servers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dns, subdomain, scalability

I maintain a web application that is outgrowing a single VPS. The architecture consists of a large number of small users, each with their own subdomain. Users do not interact. Load means i have to move some users, and all new users, to another installation of the web application on a separate server.

Currently, every user subdomain falls to the same virtualhost, where a single PHP front controller displays the appropriate content based on the hostname. A single wildcard DNS record for *.mydomain.com points to the current server.

What is my best option for routing different user subdomains to different servers?

My thoughts:

- A new top-level domain for every server. user.s1.mydomain.com, user.s2.mydomain.com and so on (inelegant and leaks information)
- Run my own DNS server to route users between servers (extra point of failure, unfamiliar technology)
- A central front controller / balancer that reverse-proxies every request to the appropriate server (extra point of failure, potentially limited connections)

Comment: Is the user-generated content for each subdomain all in a database or do they upload their own data to the filesystem on the server?

Comment: @drew010 User content is stored both in a database and on the filesystem. Since users don't interact, i can freely set up multiple database instances... the issue is just routing page queries. I suppose separating db + web servers would be another possible way of scaling out, but eventually i'll have to split the web server and will need a solution

Comment: That's what I was figuring.  I'm leaning most towards DNS but that means you will need an A record for every subdomain, or a custom DNS solution that can query your application to determine which IP address to use for the given subdomain.  You may have better results asking this on ServerFault now that I think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that point in the scaling-out of the application, I'd go with a central front load balancer. Nginx should handle any load that is being served dynamically by one single server. We have nginx as a front end for six dynamic servers and one static-content server, and there are no bottlenecks in sight on nginx.

At your scale-point, setup nginx to handle all static content itself, and reverse proxy dynamic content to as many boxes as needed. The setup for simple proxy pass is close to:

```
upstream upstream_regular_backend {
    fair;
    server 10.0.0.1:80;
    server 10.0.0.2:80;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_regular_backend;
    }
}
```

For serving static content and passing back all the rest, something like:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name  example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    index index.php;
    root /some/dir/:
    location ~ \.php {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_regular_backend;
    }
}
```

Naturally, if you are not using PHP, tweak the configuration accordingly.

On the upstream definition, "fair;" will load-balance backends based on response-time. For caching motives, you may want to use "ip_hash;" instead, as it will land requests from a client always on the same server.

Our setup is a bit further down the road. We have nginx load-balancers proxying a varnish cache, which in turn proxies the dynamic content servers.

If you are worried about nginx being a single-point-of-failure, setup a secondary server ready to assume the frontend's IP in case it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your response - seems guaranteed to work well as long as nginx can spare the open connections, and ip_hash (the missing puzzle piece) saves me from rearchitecting the application to not care about which server each request comes in on. Do you have the nginx load balancer terminate SSL?

Comment: We do terminate SSL on nginx, although not on the setup I described.

Comment: Regarding connection limits, from what I remember, the only limit we hit was the number of open file descriptors. Modify the nginx init.d and have it raise ulimit -n to as many as needed. Other than that, nginx routing traffic has excellent efficiency.